# How to charge canon eos 7D mkii using laptop and usb cable,charging the camera?

Tags: canon

How to charge canon eos 7D mkii using  laptop and usb cable port.. ,how will I know if it is charging the camera?

Comment: AFAIK (and I own a 7D Mk II), this is not possible. I believe the USB port is only for transferring images, tethering, etc, and does not have charging capability. At least the manual never states that it does.

Comment: Closely related question: [Are there any DSLRs which can charge the battery via USB?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/53237)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't. But you can use dummy battery to power the camera from USB power source (laptop, power bank, etc.) like [this](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B073ZDVX4C/ref=pd_sbs_107_4/257-3841738-9824304?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B073ZDVX4C&pd_rd_r=7e1ed443-b62a-4537-b076-3cbba048fa8a&pd_rd_w=JD1Ch&pd_rd_wg=N1srX&pf_rd_p=c8718c55-fb13-473f-a41c-592a17ad3468&pf_rd_r=43GVDBBG8VEC1VA763N3&psc=1&refRID=43GVDBBG8VEC1VA763N3).

No affiliate with the product/seller.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you'll find [USB chargers for the 7D batteries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RQPGW29) that you can connect to your laptop, or to a USB power adapter.

Comment: Output from that charger is 0.5A, which is roughly 40% of the 1.2A output of the standard Canon LP-E6 chargers. It would take roughly 8-10 hours to charge a mostly exhausted LP-E6n battery using such a charger.

Comment: @MichaelC There are [others](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JMSL54D/). But USB power is limited (2.5A@5V (12.5W) IIRC)...

Comment: Most USB power sources are limited to far less than 2.5A @ 5V, though. USB2, which is the current "lowest common denominator" is limited to 1.5A @ 5V, which the charger linked in your answer draws and steps up to 500ma(0.5A) @8.4V. The step up transformer eats roughly 45% of the power!

Comment: https://www.zdnet.com/article/usb-power-delivery-the-fastest-way-to-charge-your-iphone-and-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

You can't charge a 7D Mark II battery via the USB port. You'll need to remove the battery and use an external charger to recharge it.

The main reason seems to be that the 7.2V batteries used by the 7D Mark II and many other Canon 5-Series, 7-Series, and x0D series cameras require more voltage to charge than what the vast majority of USB chargers and ports in existence can provide.

Comment: I don't think this answer is entirely valid. If a battery can be charged quickly, it usually can be charged slowly as well.

Comment: You'll never charge a battery to 7.2-7.4 volts by applying only 5 volts to it, no matter how long you charge it. The limit of USB is 5 volts.

Comment: @Michael, boost/buck convertors exist for changing DC voltages, so it's not physically impossible to make a 7.2V charger that accepts a 5V supply.  It just means that Canon didn't impose the cost of one onto all 7D owners, when most of us find it simpler to just charge the battery externally, and keep using the camera with a different battery.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sure, but do you really want to increase the weight/size/heat output of a camera for such a small benefit? Especially since raising the voltage has an efficiency cost in terms of the very limited amperage available via usb ports? Even when it makes so much more sense to charge the battery out of the camera while another battery is powering the camera and allowing it to be used while the other battery is being charged.

Comment: Actually my original comment about slow vs quick charging was based on an old version of the answer which claimed there is not enough amperage. Now it correctly says there is not enough voltage, and I agree with both the current version of the answer and with Toby Speight's comment.

Comment: No, I don't think it's desirable; it's just that you seemed to be implying that charging 7.2V battery from 5V USB was impossible.  All the points you make help explain why it's not built into the camera (and what I just summarised as "cost"), and I fully agree with you on those!

Comment: Canon does allow charging their 7.4V batteries in the EOS RP via USB by using 9V to charge. But that requires a USB charger that is PD (Power Delivery) compliant, which eliminates over 99% of existing USB chargers in the world.

Comment: USB chargers for these batteries exist.